# Uploading attachments using json rest api

Tags: java, json, jira, apache-httpclient-4.x, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to upload attachments in to Jira using the rest api

> I've tried the following code:

```
  String pathname ="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Tool\\sample.png";
    BASE64Encoder base = new BASE64Encoder();
    String encoding = base.encode("test:test".getBytes());
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/T-6279/attachments");
    File fileUpload = new File(pathname);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    postRequest.setHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");

    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(fileUpload));
    postRequest.setEntity(entity.build());



    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    System.out.println(response);
```

And im getting this Error

[image: I'm getting this Error]

> Can you help me fix the error?

Comment: I don't think your local Jira instance (port 8080) runs over SSL. The URL should be `http://localhost:8080/rest/...`, not `https://...`.

Comment: thanks its connect working perfectly